# Xamarin Build Error Building Target

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mono, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I try to compile my simple program in Xamarin and nothing seems to work. I find it a bit buggy :(

**I have clean the project multiple times and try to build the project again. Nothing seems to work.
Do you have any ideas how to solve that?**

Error: Error building target _XamarinAndroidBuildAarProguardConfigs: Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.InvalidProjectFileException: Cycle in target dependencies detected
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target.BuildOtherTargets (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] targetNames, System.Action`1[T] missing_target, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00065] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Engine/Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine/Target.cs:263 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target.BuildDependencies (System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x0003f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Engine/Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine/Target.cs:211 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target.BuildActual (System.String built_targets_key, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00091] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Engine/Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine/Target.cs:177  (SmoochAndroid)

Answer (score 9):

Downgrading the package `Xamarin.Build.Download` from Version `0.4.6` to `0.4.5`... helped me out.

Comment: Please share additional information why if you can. Thanks your sir!

Comment: This was causing the problem for me too.  I rolled it back to 0.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade Xamarin.Build.Download back to 0.4.5 from the current 0.4.6. Still haven't found an accurate answer as to why but it worked for me. 
I found [the issue](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98777/invalidprojectfileexception-cycle-in-target-dependencies-detected-build-failed) on Xamarin's forums.